# How do I print out a field

Tags: 7, entities

I created a new content type with several fields in it. How would I print out those fields anywhere on the page that I need them like in the sidebar and other areas? What is the syntax for printing out a field? Also, I think I have to name a PHP file after the content type. What do I name it in Drupal 7?

Comment: I guess the question is about the name to use for template files.

Answer (score 2):

This is best accomplished with [Render Arrays](http://drupal.org/node/930760). Please read [Theming Node Form into Regions](http://batayneh.me/post/theming-node-form-regions) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is how to put fields from a node to the page itself. You have to use [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) and you can do something like this:

`$page['sidebar_first']['node_links']=$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['links'];` for putting node links in the sidebar.

For a field from a node you can do something like this:
`$page['sidebar_first']['test_block']=$page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$nid]['field_your_field'];`

Note: `$nid` si the desired nid from the `$page['content']['system_main']['nodes']` array.
The idea is that you can modify anything that a region contains and you can easily create blocks in any region with this hook.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install the devel module and do a

```
dpm($node);
```

You'll be able to see all the data contained in the node and therefore, you'll be able to use them as you want.

Comment: I installed the Devel Module and put in <?php echo dpm($node); ?>

Comment: And nothing happened.. Any ideas?